# Use grep to find letter without separate

Tags: r, grepl

I have these codes:

```
x=c('a','a,b','a-c','ab')
y=c('a')
grep(y,x,ignore.case = T)
```

The result is

```
> grep(y,x)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

But I expect that the result should be "1 2 3", once "a" is separated by anything or just "a", except "a" is not separated like "ab".
Thank you!

Comment: Separators have nothing to do with it.  You are telling `grep()` to look only for the character "a" and it finds it in every string.

Answer (score 3):

Add a word boundary to `y`:

```
x=c('a','a,b','a-c','ab')
y=c('a\\b')
grep(y,x,ignore.case = T)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As the OP's wants to have a pattern that involves not having any letters following 'a' (`[^a-z]`) or (`|`) it can be the end of the string `$`.

```
grep("a([^a-z]|$)", x) 
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Or if we want to be specific that either punctuation (`[[:punct:]]`) follows 'a' or  (`|`) it is the end of string, then

```
grep("a([[:punct:]]|$)", x)
#[1] 1 2 3
```